# How do I take my web server offline for maintenance when its a single server

Tags: windows-server-2008, hosting

I have a Windows 2008R2 server that hosts Sql Server and IIS for our company.

I need to take it down occasionally for updates and backup.

This is the setup

Dedicated Windows 2008R2 server hosts my Windows 2008R2 vps web server (which is the one I need to take down).

When I take this server down, I need a way to flag the domain as currently undergoing maintenance instead of host not found.

The domain points directly to my web server so when it goes down, all they see is host not found. The domain is hosted by godaddy if that helps any.

Is there a way around this? Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that when you update and backup, you shutdown/reboot the server?

Comment: Yuppers, that is part of it.

Comment: You say "dedicated" and "VPS"...is this on-premise or hosted somewhere?  Do you have control of the firewall that is NATing the external IP to the internal?

Comment: No I do not. It's a cheap hosted dedicated server, that has run great, but I need to update and backup regularly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No way around it without adding another server of some kind... There's a wide variety of options, but it all boils down to server redundancy in one form or another..

Comment: I know godaddy redirects domains quickly. If I'm going to take it down for an hour or so, would it work to redirect the site to another host for the time being and then send it back after I'm done?

Comment: GoDaddy has little to do with it. What you're asking is called DNS Failover, and is rather unreliable at best. In any case, it still has to point to another server which has to accept traffic for your domain. There are quasi-free options available, but it's still another server...

Comment: do you have an A record pointing to your server, or is it using some sort of redirector?  you can try and fast flux the DNS (IE change it, and change it back, but the TTL on the records will probably cause it to get cached some places).  Does the IP address terminate directly on the server, or is it NAT/PAT via firewall? In the latter case you can just change the nat to another server that says down for maint.  And when done change it back.

Comment: the domain is pointed directly at my server and it stops there

Answer (score 2):

Right now your configuration is:

```
DNS -> Your Server
```

So the only point where you could do anything is by redirecting the domain:

```
DNS -|   Your Server
     |-> Some Other Server Hosting 'This is Down'
```

Unfortunately, DNS gets cached so aggressively that it can be quite a while before an update, either to take your site down, or to bring it back up, would propagate everywhere.  A short TTL on the DNS record would help, but it would hurt performance a bit.

The best move in general is to have a reverse proxy or load balancer in front of your machine:

```
DNS -> Load Balancer -> Your Server
```

That way, you can change where the load balancer points, or even get the load balancer itself to host the 'This is Down' message.  It also opens you up to a more reliable configuration, where you have more than one server:

```
DNS -> Load Balancer +--> Server 1
                     +--> Server 2
```

In this configuration you may be able to take only one machine down at a time, and not have your site down at all.

Your final option incidentally, if you don't need to restart the machine, or you don't mind that the site will still be down while it's restarting, is to condense all of this onto a single machine.  Run Nginx on the machine, have it proxy to IIS normally, but show an error message when necessary.

Comment: DNS A resource records to not 'propagate'

Comment: Sorry, @ChrisS it's just a bit of convenient imagery.

Answer (score 0):

You could put haproxy in front of your Windows server, configure it with a host-status check, and configure a 'Service Not Available' page.